# Is the Model in MVVM a Domain model or POCO?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Is it OK to use my Domain Model as Model in the MVVM pattern, in the context of a WPF application? Or is the Model (in MVVM) supposed to be some POCO? I personally don't see any reason against using the Domain Model as Model of the MVVM WPF pattern.

But then the XAML elements will bind to what? Properties in the VM, which underneath are mapped to the Domain Model, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question posed in your title: neither.

In MVVM, the "model" is generally everything the other side of the viewmodel (i.e. between the viewmodel and the repository). The model can (and usually is) composed of several different additional architectures and patterns, it is normal to have services, micro services, DALs and DILs, domain models, POCOs/data entities etc all within the "model".

The domain objects and POCOs you speak of are not **the** model, they are **part of** the model. The perspective of the model that you talk of has been brought over from other patterns like MVC, where a data entity or domain object is indeed the model. The model is a little more complex than that in MVVM.

You can bind directly to a POCO in MVVM, but it's not usually a good idea unless it is a very simple one that is not subject to change (like a lookup list that is sourced from a repository). And it is usually quite a bad idea to bind to domain objects because these will contain extra functionality or information that is related to storage and retrieval but is overkill for anything shown in the UI. The other problem with domain objects is they usually don't serialize nicely (if at all - often domain objects are generated), so unless you have a very simple model it is best to transform the domain objects to POCOs as soon as practical.

So as mentioned in the [answer from Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372174/109702), you should wrap your POCOs with viewmodel classes before they are made available to the UI. The only time you shouldn't is when you don't need any property change notifications and you also don't want to leverage any further functionality on the objects (for example you won't need a context menu on the displayed item).

Answer (score 2):

> But then the XAML elements will bind to what? Properties in the VM, which underneath are mapped to the Domain Model, right?

Yes, you could reference your POCO model entity classes in your WPF application and wrap them in view model classes that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to provide support for dynamic change notifications. This is perfectly fine.

Please refer to my answer to the below question for more information about this.

[Correct way to update property in ViewModel from Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347515/correct-way-to-update-property-in-viewmodel-from-model/41348745#41348745)

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely want to wrap your domain model objects with view models. The purpose of your view model is to expose data from your model in a way that is useful to the view. For very simple applications it might seem cumbersome to add that extra layer just for change notification, but as your application becomes more complex, having a view model layer to bind to can help keep your model clean. If you are doing something quick and dirty, there is nothing stopping you from binding directly to your domain model objects.

Answer (score -1):

Yes as long as your domain model implements inotifypropertychanged you can use and bind xaml with VM properties

Comment: But that's the thing - the DM will never implement `inotifypropertychanged`. So it's more correct to say that the VM *wraps* the (Domain) Model, yes?

Comment: If you use entity framework the Poco created by it for DM implement inotify. Even VM wraps DM the underlying properties of DM should implement inotify